# How do I configure simple Java fontconfig.properties file for use on Linux

Tags: java, fonts, openjdk-11

I am using a custom Java 11 runtime on custom linux hardware, the Java runtime was not built my me.
But I have a problem my application requires access to a font and the runtime is not configured with any so I get this stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1410)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily_NoClientCode(Font.java:1384)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFamily(Font.java:1376)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.toString(Font.java:1869)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:897)
        at Fonts.main(Fonts.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:367)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:312)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
```

I can provide some fonts and I have worked out I need to create a *fontconfig.properties* and put i into the Java runtimes *lib* folder, but I am struggling to understand what I need to put into fontconfig.properties.

Can someone give me an example of how to specify a minimal set of fonts in fontconfig.properties on linux to prevent the exception occurring.

More specificially, I have a set of truetype fonts that I have put into a **fonts** folder within the **lib** folder so how do I use this set as a set of fonts available to Java

- LucidaBrightDemiItalic.ttf
- LucidaBrightRegular.ttf
- LucidaSansRegular.ttf
- LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf
- LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf
- LucidaBrightItalic.ttf
- LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf
- LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf

If I create an empty fontconfig.properties file then the first exception changes to

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getInitELC(FontConfiguration.java:465)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.initFontConfig(FontConfiguration.java:441)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:108)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:367)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:312)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
```

so this shows Java runtime is at least finding the (empty) fontconfig.properties file so if I can configure it correctly this should work.

I tried to create a very minimal fontconfig.properties file with one file but it didnt work.

```
version=1

allfonts.plain.latin-1=-monotype-times new roman-medium-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1

filename.-monotype-times new roman-medium-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/SongKong/songkong/jre/lib/fonts/ipag.ttf

awtfontpath.latin-1=/mnt/app/opt/SongKong/songkong/jre/lib/fonts
```

Comment: I'm sure you found this page.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/fontconfig.html and this example page https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/openjdk-8/jdk/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows/fontconfig.properties.shtml and https://github.com/srisatish/openjdk/blob/master/jdk/src/solaris/classes/sun/awt/fontconfigs/linux.fontconfig.properties

Comment: Seen some examples, but they are not very clear, I only need fonts for one task in my application so what I would like to know is a minimal valid fontconfig.properties file on a linux server. i.e given a single ttf font in location x what do i have to put into fontconfig.properties so that java application cause that font when a font is required.

Comment: And can i get away with just using one font or do I need to provide a set of fonts likes the Lucida ones listed in the question.

Comment: It's astonishing that they've made the simple task of adding a font file to the Java system so difficult.  Sure, all that configuration flexibility probably has its purpose.  But come on man, you also need a basic configuration directive with suitable defaults so you don't have to become an expert in the entire Java font ecosystem to add a single font file.  Windows let's you install a font file without specifying component fonts, search sequences, character exclusions, blah blah blah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jdk releases do not come with any fonts, Oracle releases generally do, so I had an idea to download an Oracle release and see what they do but the fontconfig.properties file differs significantly between Windows and UNIX releases so I needed a UNIX release.

I first downloaded *jdk-11.0.6_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz* but this had no fontconfig.properties file probably because it was just a generic linux buiild rather than tied to any in particular. Since my main dev machine is Windows I wasn't keen to try out the .deb or .rpm builds because no easy route for me to install them. So instead I download the Solaris jdk-11.0.6_solaris-sparcv9_bin.tar.gz and unzipped that.

That did contain a font.properties.src file following this structure

```
Version =1
# Component Font Mappings
# Search Sequences
# Font Filenames
# AWT X11 font paths
```

My understanding is the *Component Font Mappings* map from a *Java component font* to a *logical font name*, *Search Sequence* specifies an order to search for fonts based on the Java component fonts. *Font Filenames* map from logical font name to *actual filename* where the font is located on machine. *AWT X11 font paths* specifies from the component font name to the *actual folder* containing the actual font on machine.

So I did a *search and replace* on the file replacing *actual filename* with the location on my font on the server, and replacing *actual folder* with the location on the folder containing the actual font.

I then renamed this modified **fontconfig.proprties.src** to **fontconfig.properties** and stored it in the jre/lib folder

A simple test program that previously failed now works

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Fonts
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
         Font defaultFont = Font.decode(null);
         System.out.println(defaultFont);
     }
}
```

However I have only specified one font (ipag.ttf) to be used for different scripts and for different styles (plain, bold etc).

When I run the program the fonts are required for use with jakarta.poi (for creating an excel spreadsheet file) and this now give the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.font.CompositeFont cannot be cast to class sun.font.PhysicalFont (sun.font.CompositeFont and sun.font.PhysicalFont are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(SunFontManager.java:1086)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:965)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:903)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.findDeferredFont(SunFontManager.java:919)
    at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2120)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:506)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2246)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:469)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:530)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:275)
```

I think the problem here is that a **Physical font** was expected but because I had not specified bold, italic fonts ectera Java try to create a font based on modifications to a physical font, creating **Composite font**. But Java always expects Physical fonts to be provided for some basic styles.

So I then copied the Lucida fonts to the fonts dir, modified the fontconfig. properties file to use these these font variations as follows

```
filename.-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaSansRegular.ttf
filename.-monotype-arial-medium-i-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaSansRegular.ttf
filename.-monotype-arial-bold-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf
filename.-monotype-arial-bold-i-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf
filename.-monotype-courier_new-medium-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf
filename.-monotype-courier_new-medium-i-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf
filename.-monotype-courier_new-bold-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf
filename.-monotype-courier_new-bold-i-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf
filename.-monotype-times_new_roman-medium-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaBrightRegular.ttf
filename.-monotype-times_new_roman-medium-i-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaBrightItalic.ttf
filename.-monotype-times_new_roman-bold-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf
filename.-monotype-times_new_roman-bold-i-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1=/mnt/app/opt/jre/lib/fonts/LucidaBrightDemiItalic.ttf
```

Just kept the ipag.ttf for South East Asian scripts
and restarted application and that worked. Whether or not this will work in all circumstances I am not sure.

Comment: could you please explain, how can I find out *xlfd name* (`-monotype-arial-medium-r-normal--*-%d-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1`) knowing just a font's name (`Lucida[SansRegular]`)?